# Clean code : Using prefix get for java function name

Tags: java, naming-conventions, clean-architecture

Regarding clean code, is it bad practice to use prefix "get" for function name in java as it may be confused with java beans ?

Example : carService.getCarDetails(), customerService.getCustomers() ...

Comment: Do you mean "should I still say `getXXX` even if the implementation is not simply `return someField` i.e. the implementation of a getter of a field?"

Comment: yes maybe it's better to use getXXX only for getter a field

Comment: There is no such written rule. Follow standards set by your org. Though widly get and set prefix is used for getter and setter but no one stops you to use it anywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

If it does more you might want to say "calclulateBalance()" or "findCustomerForID(String userID)", but it is find to use "get".

Answer (score 0):

The gets and setters came from the [mutator method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method) from computer science and become popular in the Java ecosystem with the [Java Beans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans) classes. When you have a [value object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object) is common to have get methods to read the values without any business logic behind it, and some framework enforces you to have get/set methods.

However, when you start to use [Domain Driver Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design) to model your problem using the same language domain experts use ([Ubiquitous Language](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/UbiquitousLanguage.html)) you will end with methods name that makes sense for your problem domain and improves the readability.

In your case, `getCarDetails()` it´s ok when it makes sense for your business model.